# Button and Firebase Listener - OnDataChange is not Called - Android

Tags: android

We are develoing an Activity for the LOGIN that interfaces with FIREBASE.
We have a button with the OnClickListener in which is nested the AddValueListener on the DatabaseRefence
The problem is that the AddValueListener is never called, and also if we use a latch the app will freeze because the latch will never go down to zero
BUT if we comment the code under AddValueListener our app will enter in it and it works.

What we are doing wrong?

```
   package it.polito.mad17.viral.sliceapp;

    import android.animation.Animator;
    import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;

    import android.content.CursorLoader;
    import android.content.Loader;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;

    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
    import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.lang.String;

    import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

    /**
     * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
     */
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
    };
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mPhoneView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;
    private String pwdDB,phoneDB;
    private boolean cancel = false;
    private View focusView = null;
    private boolean flag=false;
    private  DatabaseReference db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        //Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        // Set up the login form.
        mPhoneView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            });
    }

    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mPhoneView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        final String phone = mPhoneView.getText().toString();
        final String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();


        boolean verifyMail = false;


        // Check for a valid phone number.
        if (phone.isEmpty()) {
            mPhoneView.requestFocus();
            mPhoneView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            return;
        }
        if (isPhoneValid(phone) == false) {
            mPhoneView.requestFocus();
            mPhoneView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_phone));
            return;
            /// / focusView = mPhoneView;
            // cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_empty_password));
            return;
        }
        //Check for a password having the right length
        //     8 >=  pwd <= 16
        if (isPasswordValid(password) == false) {
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_short_password));
            return;
        }


        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://sliceapp-a55d6.firebaseio.com/").getReference();

        System.out.println("AAAAA " + db.child("Users").child(phone).toString());

        //     Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        //        @Override
        //        public void run() {
        db.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("BEFORE FOR CYCLE", "CIAO");
//Log are never shown
                for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    System.out.println("CCCCC " + d.getKey());
                    if (d.getKey().equals(phone)) {
                        phoneDB = d.getKey();
                        System.out.println("Phone Number is " + phoneDB);
                        pwdDB = d.child("password").getValue().toString();
                        System.out.println("The password is " + pwdDB);
                    }
                }
                // latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("FAILURE", databaseError.toString());
            }

        });

    //}

     //   });



        //   t.start();

         //   try {
             //   latch.await();
           // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             //   e.printStackTrace();
            //}

    //If we comment all this code the listener is called

            System.out.println("phoneDB: " + phoneDB + " pwdDB: " + pwdDB);
        if(phoneDB.isEmpty()){
            mPhoneView.requestFocus();
            mPhoneView.setError("The phone number field is empty!");
            return;
        }else if(!phoneDB.equals(phone)){
            mPhoneView.requestFocus();
            mPhoneView.setError("The phone number is wrong!");
            return;
        }

        if(pwdDB.isEmpty()){
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            mPasswordView.setError("The password field is empty!");
            return;
        }else if(!pwdDB.equals(password)){
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            mPasswordView.setError("The password is wrong!");
            return;
        }

    //    System.out.println("phoneDB: " + phoneDB + " pwdDB: " + pwdDB);

    }
```

Android studio also give us this subclass with Async, maybe we need to use this? and How?

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mPhone;
        private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String phone, String password) {
        mPhone = phone;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mPhone)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login with firebase then you can use my code. I hope it will help you.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

static final String TAG = "FCM";

// [START declare_auth_listener]
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
FirebaseUser user;
// check if GPS enabled
 private String myID, userUid;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String android_id;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
DatabaseReference myDBRef;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(check.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    strToken = preferences.getString(DEVICETOKEN, "").toString();
    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(Login.this);
    txtLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    //setOnClick listner
   txtLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      getUserToken();
    txtRegister.setTypeface(check.NeueRegular);
           myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("localID");
    myDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                myRef.child(android_id).setValue(user.getEmail());
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "on Auth State Changed : signed_in : " + user.getEmail());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "on Auth State Changed : signed_out");
            }
                    }
    };

}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {         

        case R.id.login_btn:               
                        signIn(strEmail, strPassword);
            break;
    }
}
private void signIn(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "failed auth..",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {


                    }
                }
            });
    // [END sign_in_with_email]
}
private void getUserToken() {
    if (user != null) {
        userUid = user.getUid();
    }
}

private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String emails = edit_email.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emails)) {
        edit_email.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        edit_email.setError(null);
    }
    String passwords = edit_password.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passwords)) {
        edit_password.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        edit_password.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}
```

}